# Visual studio 2015 ,C++ project, fatal error c1510

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Hello i am a newbie at C++ and i want to create a simple "Hello World" project in VS2015.But when i hit CTRL+F5 to build/debug my program the following message comes up: **Fatal Error C1510 Cannot open language resource clui.dll**.I have no idea what that means and the microsoft page about fatal errors offers no help on how to fix this.Anyone knows what it means and how i can fix it?

I run Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit, with 12 gb RAM

Here is the code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main( ) {
 cout << Hello World\n";
  return 0; 
  }
```

I created a new project:Visual C++ empty project

Comment: Can you show us the code? How did you create the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/78a72624-b89e-4989-944d-6ce86916d2f1/fatal-error-c1510-cannot-load-language-resource-cluidll?forum=msbuild

Reinstall VS, or run repair on it.

Comment: Ok i will try repair and reinstall if needed and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar problem, the solution was simply to place clue.dll besides the corresponding cl.exe for different build types (amd64, x86_amd64, etc.)