# error in pip install channels_redis~=2.0

Tags: python, django-channels

I have some problem with install channels_redis on python 3.6 32-bit, pip 9 and windows 10 with the following errors:

fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll.
  error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 4

====================================================================

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 4

I try to find hiredis windows binaries but can't find any thing.

error log:

```
     running build_clib
     building 'hiredis_for_hiredis_py' library
     creating build\temp.win32-3.6
     creating build\temp.win32-3.6\vendor
     creating build\temp.win32-3.6\vendor\hiredis
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c              /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT /Tcvendor/hiredis/read.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\vendor/hiredis/read.obj
     fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll.
     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 4

     ----------------------------------------
     Running setup.py clean for hiredis
   Failed to build hiredis
   Installing collected packages: msgpack, hiredis, aioredis, channels-redis
     Running setup.py install for hiredis: started
       Running setup.py install for hiredis: finished with status 'error'
       Complete output from command               C:\Users\ahe\Desktop\Mou\scm\wstest\env\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import        setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\---\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\hiredis\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ahe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9to4gn6g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\---\scm\wstest\env\include\site\python3.6\hiredis:
       running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.6
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\hiredis
copying hiredis\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\hiredis
copying hiredis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\hiredis
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

running build_clib
building 'hiredis_for_hiredis_py' library
creating build\temp.win32-3.6
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\vendor
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\vendor\hiredis
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT /Tcvendor/hiredis/read.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\vendor/hiredis/read.obj
fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll.
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------

    Failed building wheel for hiredis
   Command "C:\Users\---\scm\wstest\env\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\---\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\hiredis\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9to4gn6g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\---\scm\wstest\env\include\site\python3.6\hiredis" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hiredis\
```

Comment: Do you have redis installed? Does your Visual Studio know where to find it link against?

Comment: @OlegSklyar
redis server is running. but I am not sure about Visual Studio know about link.

Comment: @OlegSklyar, can you tell me steps of install channels_redis on windows?

Comment: Have you tried running the visual studio setup and doing a repair?

Comment: No I cannot. pip will have to compile some C/C++ code against redis and that is what is failing. I have no idea how to configure it in Windows and for that specific package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio 2015 ,C++ project, fatal error c1510](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113925/visual-studio-2015-c-project-fatal-error-c1510)